# Validate string to contain only qualifying characters and a specific optional substring in the middle

Tags: php, regex, validation, preg-match, character-class

I'm trying to make a regular expression in PHP. I can get it working in other languages but not working with PHP.

I want to validate item names in an array

- They can contain upper and lower case letters, numbers, underscores, and hyphens.
- They can contain `=>` as an exact string, not separate characters.
- They cannot start with `=>`.
- They cannot finish with `=>`.

My current code:

```
$regex = '/^[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+$/';    // contains A-Z a-z 0-9 - _
//$regex = '([^=>]$)';  // doesn't end with =>
//$regex = '~.=>~';  // doesn't start  with =>

if (preg_match($regex, 'Field_name_true2')) {
    echo 'true';
} else {
    echo 'false';
};
// Field=>Value-True
// =>False_name
//Bad_name_2=>
```

Comment: You say you can get it working in other languages - can you give an example of one?

Comment: @Shane can you show us a battery of realistic strings rhat represent the normal and fringe cases that will be encountered?   You examples ALL contain `=>`. Is this _actually_ a requirement?  Are you eventually parsing the key-value expression?  Are you in control of this format? Why is this data in this format?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use negative lookarounds. Negative lookahead `(?!=>)` at the beginning to prohibit beginning with `=>`, and negative lookbehind `(?<!=>)` at the end to prohibit ending with `=>`.

```
^(?!=>)(?:[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+(=>)?)+(?<!=>)$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/IFEBTt/1)

Comment: Thank you - your pattern worked. I appreciate your time. I was smacking my head into a wall trying to get the last bit sorted.

Answer (score 3):

There is absolutely no requirement for lookarounds here.

Anchors and an optional group will suffice.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tKPjdB/1)

```
/^[\w-]+(?:=>[\w-]+)?$/
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^-- this whole non-capturing group is optional
```

This allows full strings consisting exclusively of `[0-9a-zA-Z-]` or split ONCE by `=>`.

The non-capturing group may occur zero or one time.

In other words, `=>` may occur after one or more `[\w-]` characters, but if it does occur, it MUST be immediately followed by one or more `[\w-]` characters until the end of the string.

---

To cover some of the ambiguity in the question requirements:

- If `foo=>bar=>bam` is valid, then use `/^[\w-]+(?:=>[\w-]+)*$/` which replaces `?` (zero or one) with `*` (zero or more).
- If `foo=>=>bar` is valid then use `/^[\w-]+(?:(?:=>)+[\w-]+)*$/` which replaces `=>` (must occur once) with `(?:=>)+` (substring must occur one or more times).

Comment: /^[\w-]+(?:=>[\w-]+)*$/   is correct - thank you for anticipating an unasked question. <br>I appreciate your time. Thanks.

Comment: @Shane I noticed that you've never accepted an answer on Stack Overflow.  Please read this: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/352329

Answer (score 1):

For the example data, you can use

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+=>[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+$
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+` Match 1+ times any of the listed ranges or characters (can not start with =>)
- `=>` Match literally
- `[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+` Match again 1+ times any of the listed ranges or characters
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vznldu/1)

If you want to allow for optional spaces:

```
^\h*[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+\h*=>\h*[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+\h*$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/MhQQKP/1)

**Note** that `[a-zA-Z0-9_-]` can be written as `[\w-]`

Comment: Additionally, `some=>thing=>else` would not match with your approach (dunno if it should and if it's actually worth the effort...)

Comment: I need more clarity from the OP, but this will not match `foo_bar` which _should_ qualify based on the English expression of requirements.

Comment: @mickmackusa Initially I wanted to post what you posted, but I only saw 3 examples in the comments which contain `=>` so I made it mandatory to match.

Answer (score 1):

Well, your character ranges equal to `\w`, so you could use

```
^(?!=>)(?:(?!=>$)(?:[-\w]|=>))+$
```

This construct uses a "tempered greedy token", see [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/BeVX3c/1).

---

More shiny, complicated and surely over the top, you could use subroutines as in:

```
(?(DEFINE)
    (?<chars>[-\w])             # equals to A-Z, a-z, 0-9, _, -
    (?<af>=>)                   # "arrow function"
    (?<item>
        (?!(?&af))              # no af at the beginning
        (?:(?&af)?(?&chars)++)+
        (?!(?&af))              # no af at the end
    )
)
^(?&item)$
```

See [**another demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/Iksf2c/1)